# Nothing in PIL after importing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Been struggling with this for a bit.  On a windows 10 machine.  Installed PIL with pip  Can't seem to get PIL (Pillow or pillow) to install correctly:

```
$pip install --upgrade Pillow
$pip list`
[...]
pickleshare               0.7.5
Pillow                    9.2.0
pip                       22.2.2
pefile                    2022.5.30
prometheus-client         0.11.0 
[...]
```

---

I can import PIL, but there is nothing in it:

```
>>> import PIL
>>> import datetime
>>> help ('datetime')
Help on module datetime:

NAME
datetime - Fast implementation of the datetime type.

MODULE REFERENCE
    https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime

    The following documentation is automatically generated from the Python
    source files.  It may be incomplete, incorrect or include features that
    are considered implementation detail and may vary between Python
    implementations.  When in doubt, consult the module reference at the
    location listed above.

CLASSES
    builtins.object
        date
            datetime
        time
        timedelta
        tzinfo
            timezone

    class date(builtins.object)
     |  date(year, month, day) --> date object
     |
     |  Methods defined here:
     |
     |  __add__(self, value, /)
    [...]

>>> help ('PIL')
Help on package PIL:

NAME
    PIL

PACKAGE CONTENTS


FILE
    (built-in)
```

Tried it inside spyder (conda) and natively on the system.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `from PIL import Image` followed by `dir(Image)`

Comment: That looks like you have an empty `PIL.py` file somewhere that `import` finds before the actual installed module.

Comment: I switched everything to python 3.10 and it started working.  Not sure what the underlying problem is/was.  But I'm moving forward.

Thanks!